# Add boldface text to tikzcd?

Tags: tikz-cd

I am using the tikzcd-editor. I would like to make my text bold, but only part of it. I am not sure how to make the leaves at the bottom of the tree below bold. 
tinyurl.com/y22byjbn

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide the code that produces this. BTW, I feel you'd be much better off if you produce this with `forest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it suffices to wrap your diagram into `\boldmath...\unboldmath`, or you need to use `\textbf` in the lowest nodes of a string, but this is hard to be sure about because you do not disclose the code. At any rate, such trees are IMHO to be produced with `forest`, not `tikz-cd`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={if n children=0{font=\bfseries}{execute at begin node=\boldmath$,
execute at end node=$\unboldmath}}
 [S
  [NP
   [N
    [Jacob]
   ]
  ] 
  [VP
   [V'
    [V
     [introduced]
    ]
    [NP
     [N
      [Maria]
     ]
    ]
   ]
   [PP
    [P
     [to]
    ]
    [NP
     [N
      [Sue]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or (full credit goes to @cfr):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
where n children=0{font=\bfseries}{math content}
 [S
  [NP
   [N
    [Jacob]
   ]
  ] 
  [VP
   [V'
    [V
     [introduced]
    ]
    [NP
     [N
      [Maria]
     ]
    ]
   ]
   [PP
    [P
     [to]
    ]
    [NP
     [N
      [Sue]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I never thought about doing something this way. (With the `execute` keys.) However, I'm not sure it is actually what the OP wants. (But this is obviously hard to tell given so little information in the question.) I thought the OP wanted just `where n children=0{font=\bfseries}{math content}`.

Comment: @cfr Thanks! My  is gone, so I can't say if this is what the OP wants, most likely you are right, but let's see....

Comment: Thank you! The second part was exactly what I was looking for. (Still very new to LaTeX - so I'm still learning!) Cheers

Comment: Certainly. Thanks again.